# Int and String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class CHECK {
public CHECK(){
    String []wrkrs = {"Денис", "Саша", "Наталья", "Анатолий", "Юра", "Коля", "Катя", "Дима", "Антон","Тамара"};
    int [] wrkrsPhone = {22626,22627,22628,22629,22630,22631,22632,22633,22634,22635};
    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello,friend!Do you wanna know, is that guy at work?Enter name:");


    if(Arrays.asList(wrkrs).contains(a)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That guy is at work!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "calling " + wrkrsPhone[wrkrsPhone.toString().indexOf(a)]);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Такого сотрудника нет!");
    }
}
```

I have two arrays, which contain ints and strings. As you can see, I want to add the number of elements in the string array (for example, wrkrs number 3) to the int array, called wrkrs phone. How can i do it? I tried IndexOf, but it doesn't work.

The output, i want is something like:

```
Enter name:
Юра
That guy is at work!
Calling Юра + wrkrsPhone(Юра).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
...
List list = Arrays.asList(wrkrs);
if(list.contains(a)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That guy is at work!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "calling " + wrkrsPhone[list.indexOf(a)]);
}
...
```

U better use a Map or extract a class `Contact` which have `name` and `phone` property but i think this is what u looking for :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it!)

Answer (score 5):

A better solution would be to have a Worker class that would contain the worker's name and their phone number.

Then you can use a `HashMap<String,Worker>` instead of your arrays to store the data.

This makes the search more efficient :

```
Map<String,Worker> workersMap = new HashMap<>();
workersMap.put ("Денис", new Worker ("Денис", 22626));
...
Worker worker = workersMap.get(a);
if (worker != null) {
    call (worker.getPhone()); // or do whatever you want to do with the phone number
}
```

This is more efficient than `Arrays.asList(wrkrs).contains(a)`, which performs linear search on the List.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't worked with MAP, but i'll do it soon)